# VBA_Excel_For loop going 1 value too much

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, for-loop

I am working on a VBA code and read values from a column, to then return an array with the line numbers in which the cell is empty.

Seems to be working fine, but I have one increment too much on the i loop even though it's entry is set as a fixed value. The consequence is that it creates one additional value in the "arr" array, set at 0.

Can't figure out why. Can anyone help me ?

```
Sub Main()
Dim NbrEnvoi As Integer: NbrEnvoi = 0

triEnvoi
NbrEnvoi = UBound(triEnvoi)

For i = 0 To NbrEnvoi
    row = triEnvoi(i)
'    appelFonctionMail (row)
Next

End Sub
'*******************************************************************************************
Function triEnvoi() As Variant
'trier les adhérents qui ont déjà eu leur reçu de don
Dim arr() As Integer
Dim sizeArray As Integer: sizeArray = 0

For i = 3 To LastLine
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, Range("RecuEnvoye").Column)) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(sizeArray + 1)
        sizeArray = UBound(arr)
        arr(sizeArray - 1) = i
    End If
Next
MsgBox (arr(0) & arr(1) & arr(2))
triEnvoi = arr
End Function
```

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Which `i` is too much - the one in the 1st or the 2nd function? You can always just chuck in a `-1` to your loop upper limit

Comment: Where is `i` declared? Is it Global in scope or are you not using `Option Explicit`?

Comment: It's the i in tje triEnvoi() function.
It is not declared, I thought by launching a for loop it was automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank()` function to count blanks and `SpecialCells()` method to gather them

as follows:

```
Function triEnvoi() As Variant
    Dim lastLine As Long, nBlanks As Long
    Dim cel As Range

    lastLine = 20 ' <-- fit it to your needs

    With Intersect(Range("RecuEnvoye").EntireColumn, Rows(3).Resize(lastLine - 3 + 1))
        nBlanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells)
        If nBlanks > 0 Then
            ReDim arr(1 To nBlanks)
            nBlanks = 0
            For Each cel In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                nBlanks = nBlanks + 1
                arr(nBlanks) = cel.Row
            Next
            triEnvoi = arr
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

and your `Main()` sub would then be:

```
Sub main()
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long

    v = triEnvoi

    If Not IsEmpty(v) > 0 Then
        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
            appelFonctionMail triEnvoi(i)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your question you may mark the answer as accepted to direct future readers too...

Comment: I am not just not quite sure how the "rows(3).resize" works. Can you please explain a bit more in detail ?
Cause rows is not declared anywhere, is it predefined ?
And also, I'm surprised you don't have the arr() declaration, is a direct reDim possible ?

Comment: 1) `Rows()` is a property of `Sheet` object, and this latter defaults to `ActiveSheet` when no sheet is explicitly added (e.g.: `Rows(…)` is assumed as `ActiveSheet.Rows(…)`). 2) the `Redim` acts as a decalaration itself for "dynamic" arrays , however you can have both `Dim` and then `ReDim` if you like so.

Comment: Okay so if I understand it well, the intersect is a selection of the range from row 3 to row "lastline - 3 + 1" in column "RecuEnvoye".
I am correct ?

Comment: You were nearly there: the intersect is a selection of the range from row 3 to row "lastline" in column "RecuEnvoye". (mentioning that "selection" is improperly used). Since `Resize()` method of `Range(nRows, nCols)` object resizes the range object it's being called upon to the specifcied numer of rows and columns

Comment: Very good, it is clear now :) 
One last question, you put the nBlanks in the function arguments, but it is just a local variable of this function, why not just declaring it using "dim" ?

Comment: And unfortunately the .specialcells is crashing excel everytime it executes. This is why I changed it in my code with the IsEmpty. Any idea ?
I have tried on another sheet, with only 4 cells, same result...

Comment: _".specialcells is crashing excel everytime it executes."_: do you have a Mac?...

Comment: Nope, PC. can't figure out why.

Comment: Neither do I, since that `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` is safely inside a `If nBlanks > 0 Then` block, with `nBlanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells)` -> there ARE blanks

Comment: And, of course, I tested my code before putting in the answer: are you using my **exact** code both for function and for main sub?

Comment: Yep exactly the same code. Just checked again.
When I am executing the main sub it says Argument not optional on line "v=triEnvoi" (refers to my question on nBlanks declaration as argument I guess). So I have tried executing only the triEnvoi function, without declaring the nBlanks as argument, and it crashes at .SpecialCells.
I have checked putting a breakpoint to check the value of nblanks at the countblank function, and it works fine.

Comment: see edited code: my fault I didn't take `nBlanks` out of the function parameters list

Comment: Okay so it does work now, I figured out a difference I had, that I didn't think could cause an issue. I had added "MsgBox triEnvoi(1)" and this made the code crash. 
Can you explain why ? Is it because it is a variant ?
So meening that if I want to reuse one of the values in the array triEnvoi for some calculations in another function it will not work ?

Comment: Fine. Since my code worked you may accept the answer. And if you found it (along with explanations…) useful, you may also upvote it

Comment: There you go.
Concerning the msgBox crash with the variant is it normal ?

Comment: You just have gained enough reputation… . The code `Sub main(): MsgBox triEnvoi(1): End Sub` is perfectly legal and won't throw any error. So the cause of your crash must be searched somewhere else.

Comment: Well it works when it is in sub main yes but not in function triEnvoi()...

Comment: But that way you're starting an inifinite recursive call to `triEnvoi()` function, which will eventually eat up all your memory and have Excel crash!. If you want to query some array item while still in the function, use `arr` (i.e.: `MasgBox arr(1)`) array we're filling up elements into before assigning it into`triEnvoi`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim arr(), sz As Long, c As Range
sz = 0

For Each c In Selection.Cells
    If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(0 To sz)
        arr(sz) = c.Row
        sz = sz + 1 '<< this is the ubound for the *next* item (if any)
    End If
Next c

Debug.Print Join(arr, ", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ReDimming an array you should always use a collection when the size of the array cannot be determined at compile time.

Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim NbrEnvoi As Collection
    Set NbrEnvoi = triEnvoi

    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In NbrEnvoi
        Row = item
    '    appelFonctionMail (row)
    Next item
End Sub


'*******************************************************************************************
Function triEnvoi() As Collection
    'trier les adhérents qui ont déjà eu leur reçu de don
    Set triEnvoi = New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To LastLine
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, Range("RecuEnvoye").Column)) = True Then
            triEnvoi.Add i
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: but the size of the array can be determined (see my answer)